# Drawing MKPolyline Which Follows User's Current Location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am trying to draw a path behind the user as they move, tracking their path (like Strava or FitBit apps do when a user starts a workout). So far, the map centres on the user's location but does not start drawing when the user moves. I have tried to implement this with renderForOverlay, but it fails to do so when tested. The code is as follows:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class StartWorkoutViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapsView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var allLocations: [CLLocation] = []
    
    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Start the workout
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Request user's current location
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager?.startUpdatingHeading()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        
        mapsView?.showsUserLocation = true
        mapsView?.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
        mapsView?.userTrackingMode = .follow
        mapsView?.delegate = self
        
        let noLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: noLocation, latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100)
        mapsView?.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Add location to the array and prepare to draw a line between last location and current location
        print("Location Updated")
        allLocations.append(locations[0])
        
        let previousLocation = allLocations[allLocations.count - 1]
        let newLocation = locations[0]
        
        let previousCoordinates = previousLocation.coordinate
        let newCoordinates = newLocation.coordinate
        
        var area = [previousCoordinates, newCoordinates]
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &area, count: area.count)
        mapsView.addOverlay(polyline)
    }
    
// DOES NOT WORK
    func mapView(_ mapsView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
            return polylineRenderer
        } else {
            return MKPolylineRenderer()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // If the authorisation for the user's location has changed, ask again
        if status != .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I see a few bugs: 1. call methods that change mapsView in main task (`mapsView.addOverlay(polyline)`). 2. in didUpdateLocations you add polylines but never remove the old ones. 3. `return MKPolylineRenderer()` has no overlay as parameter, so the Renderer does not know what to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you’re grabbing a location, adding it to the array, and then creating a polyline from the last location in the array, `allLocations[allLocations.count - 1]`, (which is now the current location) to the current location (i.e. to itself).

So, grab the last item, `previousCoordinate`, from the array before you add the new location to it:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let currentLocation = locations.first(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 }) else {
        return
    }

    let previousCoordinate = allLocations.last?.coordinate
    allLocations.append(currentLocation)

    if previousCoordinate == nil { return }

    var area = [previousCoordinate!, currentLocation.coordinate]
    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &area, count: area.count)
    mapsView.addOverlay(polyline)
}
```

I'd also suggest, as you see above, checking for the horizontal accuracy of the location update, to make sure it’s non-negative.

Anyway, that yields:

[image]

---

A few other observations:

1. I'd suggest retiring the `noLocation` pattern in `viewDidLoad`. My above pattern doesn't require that dummy value in the array.
2. Another issue is that in `didChangeAuthorization`, you are instantiating a new `CLLocationManager` and not setting its properties. You are therefore losing the configuration of the original `CLLocationManager` in `viewDidLoad`. There’s no need to instantiate another one, but if you do, remember to configure it properly.